# Where/How does request object's string json been converted to model object, occur at API call in MVC architecture?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, model-view-controller, serialization, deserialization

Have gone through articles in MVC, they have explained generically that request will be routed towards controller, and the deserialisation happens behind.

Comment: #JsonValueProviderFactory

Comment: Thanks @MannanBahelim